# How to change in TinyMce Editor (After The Deadline plugin) the onClick event to onMouseOver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, tinymce, onmouseover

I would like After the Deadline to react onMouseOver instead of onClick when I click on a highlighted error in the text. Here is an atd demo:
http://www.polishmywriting.com/atd-tinymce/demo.html

I suspect this line in line 177 of editor_plugin.js is responsible

```
editor.onClick.add(plugin._showMenu, plugin);
```

When I change this to onMouseOver it complains that there is no such event in TinyMce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct: onMouseOver is not a tinymce event (tinymce uses its own event handlers).
The solution looks something like

```
$(editor.getBody()).bind('mouseover', function (evt){
        alert('place code here');   
    }
);
```